# Django-CMS - Global placeholder?

Tags: django, placeholder, django-cms

Is there any way to make global placeholder in my base template? I need it to be the same on every page (banners list).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually create a page in my CMS that isn't published, but contains placeholders that I would like to use elsewhere (footer/headers) etc.

Make a new template **extra_placeholders.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "Banner-List" %}
{% endblock %}
```

add it to your settings:

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('my/path/extra_placeholders.html', 'Extra Placeholder Page'),
    ...
)
```

now go to the admin and create the placeholder with whatever plugin you want. Then go to you base template (***base.html** probably) from which all your other pages inherit and add this wherever you want the placeholder to appear:

```
{% load cms_tags %}
...
{% show_placeholder "Banner-List" "extra_placeholders" %}
```

[You can read more about it in the docs](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.3/advanced/templatetags.html#show-placeholder)

---

**EDIT**

As @José L. Patiño has mentioned in the comments, this solution is only necessary for those using `django-cms` < 3.0. For the newer version you can simply use the [`static_placeholder`](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#static-placeholder) template tag

Comment: I made it very similar, but I used Homepage as a place to keep my global placeholders. Thanks.

Comment: Note that for the `show_placeholder` tag to work, your "Extra Placeholder Page" **must** have id set to "extra_placeholders" under the "Advanced Settings" section. It's not smart enough to figure that out directly from the slug...

Comment: The problem here is that the placeholders that belong to the `extra_placeholders` page are not published in the edition mode of the the front end interface. One must to go to the admin open the page and publish the page from there. This is very confusing for the final content editors. Any idea?

Comment: I posted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575747/how-to-use-post-publish-signal-to-publish-a-related-page-referenced-by-show-plac)

Comment: Nice solution for Django CMS versions before 3.0. For newer 3 versions, it is implemented in static-placeholder template tag https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#static-placeholder

Answer (score 7):

There is the "static_placeholders" now, http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#static-placeholder

Sounds like it's what you needed way back when.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer as the currently accepted answer is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following ways to create a global palceholder for all pages.

1. create a place holder on the base page. {% Placeholder "footer"%}
2. make the contents of the placeholder through django cms as home page
3. then to display the same for each placeholder page, add {% show_placeholder "footer"    "home"%}, this means displaying the newly created footer placeholder earlier from the home page,
4. This will display the entire contents existing footer placeholders on the home page of all pages that use the template.
5. but for the home page there will be two footer is displayed, to mengilangkannya, please do modifications to use CSS to hide the master placeholder.