# How to use post_publish signal to publish a related page referenced by show_placeholder?

Tags: django, django-cms

I am using `show_placeholder` to display "global" content along my site. For example, a Widget that I use in the sidebar. I did something similar to the suggestions given in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368848/django-cms-global-placeholder). I created a template `extra_placeholders.html` and a page (with return id "extra-placeholders") in the admin that use `extra_placeholders.html` to store the placeholders. It is never displayed in the front end but I can access the placeholder of it with `{% show_placeholder "my_placeholder" "extra-placeholders" %}`

It works fine with one caveat that I need to solve. Let's say I use the front-end "Edition Mode" of Django-CMS to edit the placeholder. It works in the sense that I can modify the content and save it.

However, **it does not get published automatically**.

I understand the reason. The placeholder actually belongs to another page ("extra-placeholders"). So when I click "Publish" in the front end I save the page that I am seeing but not the one associated through the `my_placeholder`.

So, I would like to use a signal to save the "extra-placeholders" page each time any other page is saved. I found that there is [this signal](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/signals/page.py#L22) but how do I use it to publish my extra-placeholders page?

Comment: [this seems](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/signals/__init__.py#L24) to be the correct signal

Comment: Can you confirm which version of the CMS you're using?

Comment: I get the sense that you're using version 3.0. If so, have you considered using static placeholders (http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/develop/advanced/templatetags.html#static-placeholder)?

Comment: Static placeholders sounds like heaven. I have been struggling with my `extra-placeholders` everywhere. Unfortunately, I am working with a production site and using version 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to connect a signal to `CMSPlugin`, not `Page`.

Something like this (untested!) might work:

```
def signal_handler(instance, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(instance, CMSPlugin):
        return
    page = Page.objects.get(reverse_id='extra-placeholders', publisher_is_draft = True)
    if page.placeholders.filter(pk=instance.placeholder_id).exists():
        page.publish()

post_save.connect(signal_handler)
```

Comment: this is almost working, however `page = Page.objects.get(reverse_id='extra-placeholders')` is return two pages and prompting an error. I know that django-cms keeps to copies of the page. One for the draft and another for the published, but what other parameter should I use.\

Comment: The `publisher_is_draft` would do it: `page = Page.objects.get(reverse_id='extra-placeholders', publisher_is_draft = True)`

Comment: It also doesn't work with the abstract/base class `CMSPlugin`, it has to be exactly the derived class, for example, `FilerImage`. I have had this problem before. Any idea?

Comment: I edited your answer with the problems I encounter. Thanks a lot!